# How can I make my bash script create an ssh key pair for a given user

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting. I wrote a script that can create groups and users which works just fine, but my challenge now is how do I make the script create an ssh key pair for a particular user. From my script, it stopped working immediately after you switch to that user and it doesn't proceed to create the ssh key pair.

Below is my script.

```
    for group in admin support engineering
    do
            sudo groupadd $group
            sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash achebeh_${group}
    done
    sudo passwd achebeh_admin
    sudo su achebeh_admin
    ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

So please how can I go about creating an ssh pair for the achebeh_admin user using this script. I am open to learn. Please this is my firs script after following a tutorial course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Achebe-peter If I got your requirements correctly from your short description, this will do the job for you.

*Note:*

- *Try this script in a test environment at your own risk!*
- *This script best performs assuming that you don't have configured users and related files*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
### Configuration Parameters Start ###
## The username that doesn't exist and you want to create.
user_name_prefix='testuser'

## The groups array that doesn't exist and you want to create and assign them to your user.
groups=(testadmin testsupport testengineering)

## SSH-key lenght
ssh_key_lenght='2048'
### Configuration Parameters End ###


for group in ${groups[@]} ;do
  # Set username containing the prefix and group name
  user="${user_name_prefix}_${group}"

  # create such user if not exist
  getent passwd ${user} &>/dev/null
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ;then
    sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash "${user}"

    echo -e "\nType password for: ${user}"
    sudo passwd ${user}
  fi

  # Create '.ssh' directory in user's home directory
  if ! [ -d /home/${user}/.ssh ] ;then
    sudo mkdir /home/${user}/.ssh
  fi

  # Generate ssh-key pair and move them to correspondig user's '.ssh/' dir.
  ssh_file_name="./${user}_ssh"
  (
  echo "${ssh_file_name}"
  echo ""
  echo "" 
  ) | ssh-keygen -t rsa -b ${ssh_key_lenght}

  sudo mv -i "${ssh_file_name}" "${ssh_file_name}.pub" /home/${user}/.ssh/
  sudo chown ${user}:${user} /home/${user}

  # Create the groups (if does not exist)
  getent group ${group} &>/dev/null
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] ;then
    sudo groupadd ${group}
  fi

  # Assign relevant group to the new user
  sudo usermod -aG ${group} ${user}
done

exit 0
```

###### Tested in

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

PS. Please vote up my answer and mark it as the correct answer if it satisfies your requirements.